# Minecraft Forge Item Block Render Issue

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I am having an item block rendering issue, as when I place the block, it renders correctly, but when I hold it in my hand, it has a missing texture/model.

An image of what I see is in the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/atq1L.png

I have checked many times for the reason, and there is no error message in the console, there does not appear to be any problems with the JSON formatting, and there seems to be no problem in the code.

*By the way, the code for the block class is not too important because it is just a class that extends *Block.class, then gives the super with Material.stone

Here is my code for my blocks class:

```
package com.kraftymods.luckyblocks.init;

import com.kraftymods.luckyblocks.blocks.LuckyBlock;
import com.kraftymods.luckyblocks.blocks.itemblocks.LuckyBlockItem;
import com.kraftymods.luckyblocks.main.Reference;

import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.resources.model.ModelResourceLocation;
import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;

public class Blocks {

    public static Block luckyblock;

    public static void init(){
        luckyblock = new LuckyBlock().setUnlocalizedName("luckyblock")[enter image description here][1].setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabMisc);
    }

    public static void register(){
        GameRegistry.registerBlock(luckyblock, LuckyBlockItem.class, luckyblock.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    }

    public static void registerRenders(){
        registerRender(luckyblock);
    }

    private static void registerRender(Block block){
        Item item = Item.getItemFromBlock(block);
        Minecraft.getMinecraft().getRenderItem().getItemModelMesher().register(item, 0, new ModelResourceLocation(Reference.MODID + ":" + item.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5), "inventory"));
    }

}
```

Here is the code for my JSON files:

Blockdata:

```
{
    "variants": {
        "normal": { "model": "luckyblocks:luckyblock" }
    }
}
```

Block Model:

```
{
    "parent": "block/cube_all",
    "textures": {
        "all": "luckyblocks:blocks/luckyblock"
    }
}
```

Item Model:

```
{
    "parent": "luckyblocks:block/luckyblock",
    "display": {
        "thirdperson": {
            "rotation": [ 10, -45, 170 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 1.5, -2.75 ],
            "scale": [ 0.375, 0.375, 0.375 ]
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate the time you took to read this

Comment: Wow kind of cool to see my first minecraft post. Sorry I can't answer, but there's another stack exchange you can go to mean for game developing call "Game Development".

Comment: Make shure that you are modding in the forge folder directly. do not copy the files to another folder. that causes most of the rendering issues

Comment: I am modding into the forge folder directly, everything is in their assets folder respectively, the blockstate file is in the modid/blockstates, the models folder in their respective location as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make a class for clientside purposes in which you register your renderers

I have this for example:

```
public final class BlockRenderRegister {
    public static void registerBlockRenderer() {
        register(BlocksLibrary.blockDarkStone);
    }
    public static void register(Block block) {
        Minecraft.getMinecraft().getRenderItem().getItemModelMesher()
                .register(Item.getItemFromBlock(block), 
                          0, 
                          new ModelResourceLocation(
                                ModHooks.MODID.toLowerCase() + ":" + BlocksLibrary.DARKSTONE, 
                                "inventory"
                                 )
                          );
    }
}
```

And for loading your blocks I also suggest a seperate class(just for maintenance purposes

```
public class BlockLoader {
    /**
     * Loads all blocks into memory
     * and populates the BlocksLibary
     * with decent values.
     */
    public static void loadBlocks() {
        GameRegistry.registerBlock(
                BlocksLibrary.blockDarkStone = new BlockDarkStone(Material.rock),
                BlocksLibrary.DARKSTONE
                );
    }
}
```

I register the blocks in the PreInit event so the game knows my blocks.

```
@EventHandler
public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent e) {
    BlockLoader.loadBlocks();
}
```

And I call this from the FMLInitializationEvent in my main mod class to register the renderers.

```
@EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event) {
        BlockRenderRegister.registerBlockRenderer();
    }
```

Comment: I will look at it when I get back, but it looks like you are suggesting the same thing, but in a different format (as you say)